# AWS Lambda +API Gateay image resizing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, python-imaging-library

I want to create a dynamic image resizing function which will take an image from my S3 storage and return a resized version of this image.

I have managed to get the image and resize it, saving it back into S3, however I want to return the image, which will then be passed into my API gateway. Currently I am using Boto3 get_object method which returns a dict. If I use download_file, I get None return.

```
response = client.get_object(Bucket = 'bucket-images' , Key = 'img.png')

s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

How can i return the image in a format which can then be used by my API Gateway. (i ahve set the method response type in the gateway to be image/png, ready for when the lambda function is working.